# Continuity and Differentiability of A Piecewise Function at (0,0)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

> Let $$
> f(x,y) = \left\{
> \begin{split} x\quad & \text{if } y=x^2 \\  0 \quad & \text{otherwise}
> \end{split}
> \right.
> $$
>   Prove that, at $0$, the function $f$ has directional derivatives in all directions and that it is continuous at $0$.
>
> Prove that $f$ is not differentiable at 0.

So $$D_vf(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$, how would i compute it with the condition y=x^2? and to prove it is not differentiable at 0, I have to prove that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-h}{h}$$ does not equal to 0? Again, I am a little confused on the condition y=x^2. Same with continuity. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: You seem to be confused.  Your formulas treat $f$ as if it were a function of one variable, but it's a function of two variables.  Your first formula has a $v$ on the left-hand side, but none on the right-hand side.  Also, the derivative of a function of two variables is a linear transformation, remember?  Look over your notes again.

Comment: what does the linear transformation have to do here? do you mean i should not include the h?

Comment: What is the definition of differentiability given in your textbook, or in your notes?

Answer (score 2):

1. Continuity at 0:
   This can be readily seen with $\epsilon-\delta$-criterion:
   $\forall \epsilon $, set $ \delta = \epsilon $, then for all $(x,y)$ in $ B_\delta$(0) : $|f(x,y)-f(0)| \leq |x| \leq \epsilon$
2. Directional Derivatives: Let $v = (v_1,v_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be fixed. Then, for arbitrary $h \neq 0$, $f( (0,0)+(hv_1,hv_2) ) = f(hv_1,hv_2)$. 
   We have that $(hv_2)^2 = hv1 \iff h(hv_2^2 - v1) = 0 \iff hv_2 = v_1 $. This eqation has just a finite number of solution, which makes it obvious (similar as in 1.), that if you choose a sufficiently small $h´$, $f((0,0) + vh ) - f(0,0) = 0 \ $ for all $h, |h|< h'$, i.e. the directional derivative is 0.
3. Differentiability in 0: Consider the sequence $(x,y)_n := (\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n^2}), n\in \mathbb N$. Clearly, this converges to $ (0,0)$. But, $\frac{f((x,y)_n)-f(0,0)}{||(x,y)_n - (0,0)||} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{\frac{n^2+1}{n^4}}} = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} \xrightarrow{n->\infty} 1 \neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good discussion of directional derivatives in [Paul's Online Math Notes.](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DirectionalDeriv.aspx)  I highly recommend this resource.  Note that if you can compute the partial derivatives, you can easily compute the directional derivatives.  In this case, the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ are both $0$, so all the directional derivatives are $0$.

The derivative of $f$ at $\mathbf{0}$ is the unique linear transformation $Df_\mathbb{0}$ such that $$\lim_{\mathbf{X}\to\mathbf{0}}{\lVert f(\mathbf{X})-Df_\mathbf{0}(\mathbf{X})-f(\mathbf{0})\rVert\over\lVert\mathbf{X}\rVert}=0$$ 
If $\mathbf{X}\to\mathbf{0}$ along the line $x=0$ this reduces to $$ \lim_{\mathbf{X}\to\mathbf{0}}{\lVert Df_\mathbf{0} (\mathbf{X})\rVert\over\lVert\mathbf{X}\rVert}=0,$$and the only linear transformation that will make this true is $Df_{\mathbf{0}}=\mathbf{0}$.  However, this transformation doesn't work if $\mathbf{X}\to\mathbf{0}$ along the line $y=x^2$.  Check it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For the directional derivatives consider:
$$\frac{f((hv_1,hv_2))-f((0,0))}{h}=\begin{cases}v_1,v_2=hv_1^2\\0\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
and see that in case $v_1\neq 0$  this quotient equals $0$ for $h<\frac{v_2}{v_1^2}$ in case $v_2>0$ and for $h>\frac{v_2}{v_1^2}$ in case $v_2<0$ to see:
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f((hv_1,hv_2))-f((0,0))}{h}=0.$$
Similarly you proceed  to show continuity. To see it is not differentiable note the last sentence in saulspatz's comment and see that the only linear mapping $A:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that might fit would be the zero-map, but that this doesn't work.